# Find the unduplicated element in a sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, complexity-theory

***Source : Microsoft Interview Question***

Given a sorted array, in which every element is present twice except one which is present single time, we need to find that element.

Now a standard O(n) solution is to do a XOR of list, which will return the unduplicated element (since all duplicated elements cancel out.)

Is it possible to solve this more quickly if we know the array is sorted?

Comment: Do a binary "search" (rather traversal) on the array, check both neighbors, if bot are different from the middle value, you have the solution. This is `O(log n)`.

Comment: @H2CO3 how so? Wouldn't the neighbors always be different?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei Nopeeeee! I just don't speak English. If the array is sorted, (`1 1 2 2 3 4 4`), then one neighbor is the same as the central value.

Comment: @H2CO3 Are you assuming that all the elements are consecutive? If not, how do you decide whether to check the low half or the high half?

Comment: @jerry sorted array = consecutive!

Comment: @jerry Uh, I don't get that. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @H2CO3 I was asking if you were assuming that there were no skipped numbers (as in your example). Based on Daniel Fiscer's answer, I understand what you were thinking. I blame my illness :)

Comment: @jerry No, I wasn't - the "am I present twice in the array" aspect has little to nothing to do with the distance of consecutive elements :) The thing is that if the array is sorted, then equal elements are always neighbors - and my approach (ab)uses that fact ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can use the sortedness to reduce the complexity to `O(log n)` by doing a binary search.

Since the array is sorted, before the missing element, each value occupies the spots `2*k` and `2*k+1` in the array (assuming 0-based indexing).

So you go to the middle of the array, say index `h`, and check either index `h+1` if `h` is even, or `h-1` if `h` is odd. If the missing element comes later, the values at these positions are equal, if it comes before, the values are different. Repeat until the missing element is located.

Comment: That's brilliant.  Great answer!

Comment: And now you're getting upvoted for the answer I posted in my comment 3 minutes ago. Sill me :)

Comment: @H2CO3 I was typing the answer while you were commenting, great minds think alike, don't they? But you're getting upvotes too, deservedly.

Comment: You're implicitly assuming the elements are consecutive. I'm not sure that's warranted based on the problem description.

Comment: @jerry No he is not, but this is just devilishly brilliant:)

Comment: @jerry No. All that matters is that the elements are sorted (doesn't even really matter, all we need is that the duplicated elements are next to each other).

Comment: @Ziyao sure he is: `each value occupies the spots 2*k and 2*k+1`. This is not true for, say, `{1,1,5,5,7,10,10}`.

Comment: @jerry Sure, `5` occupies 2 and 3, `1` occupies 0 and 1.

Comment: @jerry please note that `k` is not the value, it is just as saying even numbers are `2k`.

Comment: I stand corrected, I misunderstood `k` to be the value in question. I clearly didn't read the last paragraph closely enough. Have a +1 :)

Comment: @H2CO3 Now the question is, did you reciprocate, or did I?

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, that's a good question. If you upvoted as well, then we can just agree that we were equally kind to each other ;)

Comment: @H2CO3 Not for the first time, I believe, nor for the last ;)

Comment: seems like my question,has bought brotherhood :P

Answer (score 6):

Do a binary "search" (rather traversal) on the array, check both neighbors, if both are different from the value in the middle, you have the solution. This is `O(log n)`.

Comment: you didnt understand d question,i think !

Comment: @Spandan I understood it perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, The array is sorted so we can apply binary search to find the single element. Let's see the pattern of occurrence of single element. Total number of elements will be always odd and single element occurs only at even index

[image: Total number of elements 9, single elements always present at even index]

Total number of elements 9, single elements always present at even index.
When `(end_index - start_index) % 4 == 0`, The single element is occurring in middle.

```
if A[mid-1] == A[mid] --> single element left side
if A[mid] == A[mid+1] --> single element right side
```

[image: Total number of elements 11]

Total number of elements 11, single elements always present at even index. When `(end_index - start_index) % 4 != 0`, The single element is not occurring in middle.

```
if A[mid] == A[mid+1] --> single element left
if A[mid-1] == A[mid] --> single element right
```

[image]

Total number of elements 13, single elements always present at even index. When `(end_index - start_index) % 4 == 0`, The single element is occurring at middle also.

```
if A[mid-1] == A[mid] --> single element left side
if A[mid] == A[mid+1] --> single element right side
```

Below is the Python Code:

```
class Solution:
    def singleNonDuplicate(self, A):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        L = len(A)

        def binarySearch(A, start, end):
            if start == end:
                return A[start]

            if start < end:

                mid = int(start + (end - start)/2)

                if A[mid-1] < A[mid] < A[mid+1]:
                    return A[mid]
                if end - start == 2:
                    if A[end] != A[end-1]:
                        return A[end]
                if end - start == 2:
                    if A[start] != A[start+1]:
                        return A[start]
                if A[mid] == A[mid+1]:
                    if int(end-start)%4 == 0:
                        return binarySearch(A, mid+2, end)
                    else:
                        return binarySearch(A, start, mid-1)

                elif A[mid-1] == A[mid]:
                    if int(end - start)%4 == 0:
                        return binarySearch(A, start, mid-2)
                    else:
                        return binarySearch(A, mid+1, end)

        return binarySearch(A, 0, L-1)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    s = Solution()
    A = [1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]
    r = s.singleNonDuplicate(A)
    print(r)
```