# find the nonrepeating element in a sorted array

Tags: arrays, sorting

There is a sorted array which is of very large size. In it every element is repeated more than once except one element. 
How can I find the unrepeated element in O(log n) time complextiy.

Comment: Is there a constant number of times that each element (except for that one element) is repeated?

Comment: if you knew items are repeated exactly x times you could use indexes.. dosent seem possible this way..

Comment: How can you expect to do it in O(log n) when visiting each element takes at least O(n)?

Comment: Are you allowed to create any additional structures? Because if you don't care about space - you can create something like hash-map and re-use it later as many times as you wish

Comment: @Akash Goyal  If each repeating element repeats the same number of times , then it can be done in log(N) time complexity , otherwise we have to do a linear search , see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117375/find-the-unduplicated-element-in-a-sorted-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say it cant be done. Had the question been something along [these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117375/find-the-unduplicated-element-in-a-sorted-array), where every element repeats exactly twice, than the index of the element could be deduced. I am guessing the OP misunderstood the question.